# javascript changing images

Tags: javascript, image

Hello I would like to ask your help regarding javascript code, how do I have this work?

I have saved the images in my D drive. Do I need to change some path here:

Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

<!--
var image1=new Image()
image1.src="pic001.png"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="pic002.png"
var image3=new Image()
image3.src="pic003.png"
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="slidit()">
<img src="pic001.png" name="slide" width="400" height="120" />


<script>
<!--
//variable that will increment through the images
var step=1
function slideit(){
//if browser does not support the image object, exit.
if (!document.images)
return
document.images.slide.src=eval("images"+step+".src")
if (step<3)
step++
else
step=1
//call function "slideit()" every 1 seconds
setTimeout("slideit()",1000)
}
slideit()
//-->
</script>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have saved the images in my D drive.
>   Do I need to change some path here

Why give static/absolute path? Use relative path in your webapp. And if you are just practicing with single HTML then just put all the images in same folder in which HTML resides.

---

### Relative Path

It means the file path to where the image is located "relative" to the HTML page. In other words you determine the path to the image with the HTML page as the starting point. For example:-

```
<img src="../images/img.jpg" />
```

### Absolute Path

Absolute paths are a different than Relative paths in that it doesn't matter where the image files are located relative to your web pages. This is because you tell the browser exactly where the file is on the web.Example:-

```
<img src=" D/Web/pic001.png" />
```

See [this](http://www.webdiner.com/webadv/begin/paths.htm) for more help.

---

In your code following is the code where you use image path:

```
var image1=new Image()
image1.src="pic001.png"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="pic002.png"
var image3=new Image()
image3.src="pic003.png"
```

---

***Update:-***

Because your html and images are in same folder you should write like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<!--
var image1=new Image()
image1.src="pic001.png"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="pic002.png"
var image3=new Image()
image3.src="pic003.png"
//-->
</script>
```

---

***My demo working code:***

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var image1 = "./images/img02.jpg"
            var image2 = "./images/img03.jpg"
            var image3 = "./images/img04.jpg"
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="slidit()">
        <form name="images">
            <img src="./images/img01.jpg" name="slide" width="200" height="200" />
            <script>
                //variable that will increment through the images
                var step = 1
                function slideit(){
                    //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
                    switch(step){
                        case 1:
                            document.images.slide.src = image1;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            document.images.slide.src = image2;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            document.images.slide.src = image3;
                            break;
                    }
                    if (step < 3) {
                        step++
                    }
                    else {
                        step = 1
                    }
                    //call function "slideit()" every 1 seconds
                    setTimeout("slideit()", 1000)
                }

                slideit()
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Above is my demo code which is working fine. I have made some changes in your code it will now change image on interval. I hope this is what you want. You have to change image path as you used in your code other things are okay and ready to go.

Comment: @Harry Joy: Ok. Sorry I don't quite understand what is the static path and relative path? Would be helpful if you could tell me where it is in the code. Thanks

Comment: @Harry Joy: I would like to practice JS. I have all the pictures in the same folder by the way.

Comment: @tintincute: I tried to explain relative and absolute path in my answer take a look.

Comment: @Harry Joy: Thanks, I did try it but it didn't work. I edited my question above. Is that correct now?

Comment: @tintincute: where is your html file? in which folder? can you show us folder structure that contains both html file and image?

Comment: @Harry Joy: I saved it on my Desktop

Comment: @tintincute: and where XAMP_localServer reside?

Comment: @Harry Joy: That is on my D: Drive

Comment: @tintincute: then you should give relative path from your desktop to D drive. Like if your desktop path is "c:\users\harry\desktop" then you should write something as "../../../../D:/path_to_image" . you can use `../` to go up directory and then give your path.

Comment: @Harry Joy: I did. I actually copy now the test2.html file on the folder of XAMMP_LocalServer and then changed the path of the images. (please see above)

Comment: @tintincute: then you should try `"./Test/Web/pic001.png"`

Comment: @Harry Joy: Ok I copied the test2.html on the folder Web now and it when I launched the html file there but it's not changing. How can I have the picture change?

Comment: @tintincute: by calling your `slideit()` function may be at `onload` in body tag.

Comment: @Harry Joy: How can I call it? Do I have to add an additional code?

Comment: @tintincute: instead of this `<body>` write this `<body onLoad="slidit()">`

Comment: @Harry Joy: What about the closing do I have to write this: </body onLoad="slidit()">

Comment: @tintincute: no. only in opening tag.

Comment: @Harry Joy: It's not changing still. Check my edited question above it's not changing

Comment: @Harry Joy: it's edited already, kindly check. I don't understand why the picture is not changing?

Comment: @tintincute: change you this line `document.images.slide.src=eval("images00"+step+".src")` to `document.images.slide.src=eval("images"+step+".src")`

Comment: @Harry Joy: I changed it and also edited my question, (please see above) but it's still not working

Comment: @Harry Joy: Already changed my code but still it doesn't change. It only display 1 picture and nothing changed. ALso edited my answer (please check)

Comment: @tintincute: Now let me try your example.

Comment: @Harry Joy: Thank you. it seems to work. Is there a way how to have the pictures fade slowly? I changed the seconds into 3.5 seconds, but when it changed, it changed very quick. Would like to know if I can have the pictures changed smoothly?

Comment: @tintincute: sorry but I can't help you with this. But if you search you will easily find a script for fade effect in javascript.

Comment: @tintincute: how about accpeting/upvoting my answer? At least I solve your first problem[As Per I Think].

Comment: @tintincute: by clicking on uparrow above the score of my answer(which is 0 at the time of this writing).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to add absolute paths in your JavaScript. It is better to locate them in folders containing your root page. From there on, use relative paths.

Comment: @Gunner: Thanks for the reply. Should it be like this: D/Web/pic001.png?

Comment: No need for D, just use "images/pic001.png", assuming that all files are inside a folder names images and images is located inside the root directory where you main page resides.

Comment: @Gunner: But these are all in my local drive. I also saved the HTML on my desktop

Comment: @tintincute: Why don't you locate them in the same folder.

Comment: @Gunner: What do you mean, same folder? Yes they are all in the same folder?

Comment: @tintincute: Then you shouldn't face any problem if the images and your html file is in same page.

Comment: @Gunner: Maybe I'm wrong. I have the test2.html file saved on my desktop and then the images on my D: Drive.

Comment: @tintincute: Why you have the images on D drive, have them in the same folder.

Comment: @Gunner: Ok I already have them in the same folder...but it's not working :-(